# How to match orientation and scale of two different image of the same object in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have 2 images of printed circuit boards (PCB) both showing the same PCB. The differences between them are lighting, scale and orientation (because I take PCB images with my phone camera).

Now I want to use one image of the PCB to check if all the components of the circuit is assembled on another identical PCB.

Is there a convenient way to check differences between two images of two identical PCB?

Btw, I can add some marks on PCB so that in OpenCV I can correct the orientation and scale of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCB = printed circuit board, right?!?

You could probably compute a projective [projective transformation or homography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography) between matched points in both images. This transformation can be used to match planes (like your PCBs) and considers scale, rotation, shear and projective changes between your images.

It's very simple method:

Select at least 4 points and solve a system of linear equations. Take a look at the answer to this question on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494238/how-to-compute-homography-matrix-h-from-corresponding-points-2d-2d-planar-homog) which explains exactly that.

This [OpenCV example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) uses (automatic) feature matching to find corresponding image points and then computes a homography.

The also interesting derivation of this transformation can be found in every computer vision text book, e.g. THE standard Zisserman's ["Multiple View Geometry"](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/) or Ma's ["An Invitation to 3-D Vision"](http://vision.ucla.edu/MASKS/).

**EDIT:**

This method will not remove specular reflections or other intensity differences.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for